# What is the correct syntax for setting up a simulation using a system of ODEs?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, syntax

```
sys = {m x''[t] == s ω y'[t] - h (x'[t])^2, 
       m y''[t] == s ω y'[t] - h (y'[t])^2 - m g, 
       x'[0] == xdo, x[0] == 0, 
       y'[0] == ydo, y[0] == 0 };

parms = {m = .0459, s = .1, ω = 100 π, g = 9.8};
ics = {xdo = V Cos[θ], ydo = V Sin[θ], V == 61.69, θ = 12 °};
sol = NDSolve[sys /. parms //. ics, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 4}];
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I am brand new to *Mathematica* and have been watching numerous tutorials and still cannot get anywhere. My code simulates a golf ball flight in 2 dimensions. I am not interested in the algebraic solution at all, but rather with the parametric plot. When I enter this code I get numerous errors. I have multiple other variations of these equations that I also need to plot, but I am starting with the simplest of these with no luck at all. I am sure this is not even close to what I need, so I am hoping someone with more experience in *Mathematica* will lend me some guidance in how to approach this.

Comment: Your `parms` and `ics` have to be `Rules` and you have to provide what `h` is. You should execute your expressions line by line to see what the output of each is to identify errors early.

Comment: I also recommend substituting `100. π` for `100 π`

Comment: And define `h` ...

Comment: You might enjoy [this demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FlightOfAGolfBall/) as well.

Comment: @Matariki Good idea to evaluate line by line - user6895 should remove the semicolons first, though...

Answer (score 2):

I've made some changes to your code. You can use this as a starting point to make it do what you want. I also set `h = 1` since you didn't give a value for it. Note the positions of `V` and `θ`.

```
sys = {m x''[t] == s ω y'[t] - h (x'[t])^2, 
  m y''[t] == s ω y'[t] - h (y'[t])^2 - m g, 
  x'[0] == xdo, x[0] == 0, 
  y'[0] == ydo, y[0] == 0}; 
parms = {m -> .0459, s -> .1, ω -> 100. π, g -> 9.8, h -> 1.}; 
ics = {V -> 61.69, θ -> 12 °, xdo -> V Cos[θ], ydo -> V Sin[θ]}; 
sol = NDSolve[sys /. parms //. ics, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 4}]; 
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 4}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

Now, I don't know if this does what you want, but it doesn't give any errors and produces a graph. Whether it's the correct graph will depend on the actual question which you did not provide.

[image]

Comment: When I copy this directly into my notebook I still get numerous errors. I also am curious how you get those arrows that define the constants? I was under the assumption that == would do it?

Comment: The first error is that the input is not an ordinary differential equation, which I already knew so I am not sure why it says it is. A majority of the other errors state that (a number) cannot be used as a variable.

Comment: @user6895, what version of MMA are you using? Because it works for me on V9.0.1

Comment: It says Mathematica 9.0 at the top of my notebook.

Comment: Can you show me what the graph looks like? I am just curious as to what the graph looks like.

Comment: @user6895, can you start a new session and copy and paste this. I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @user6895 Try Clear["`*"] first…

Comment: @user6895, I've added the graph

Comment: Now it works but it is not the correct graph. The graph should look something close to the flight of a golf ball. The equation is the same that my instructor had yet his graph looks nothing like this.

Comment: @user6895 Well, you should post the actual mathematical equations then. Since I don't know what you're trying to achieve, I just tweaked your code to make it work.